# How do I lower tris caused by hair?

Tags: particles

I made fuzzy boots and the actual mesh only makes up for 30% of all tris. The rest is because of the fuzz on the boots. How can I lower the amount of tris caused by hair/fuzz without ruining the boots?

Comment: Instance planes with a fur texture, perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I learned that it wasn't the fur but instead the Bezier Curve which is causing my model to have 8k extra tris, still don't know how to fix this but at least I know where the problem lies. (update) I learned that the Bezier curve has resolution and the higher the resolution, the more tris. What I did to get the least tris was simply make the resolution to 0, this doesn't affect the final product in any way from what I've seen.